# Is it possible to Invoke a trigger via process builder?

Tags: trigger, process-builder

I have a requirement where I need to update/insert Cases/activity object records based on the actions happening on the 3 other objects ie Service Account, Repossession and Collateral Auction. These are all custom objects. I was planning to write the trigger only on 'Service Account' object and write whole logic even if something is happening on the field update of Repossession/Collateral auction object.

I thought I will put a process builder on these(Repossession/collateral Auction) objects when the field updates happen and then invoke the trigger in the update actions. Is this possible via process builder ? Or will I have to write separate triggers for each object fields update actions ??

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the relationships between your objects and the exact logic, you may be able to use the @InvocableMethod annotation and call your logic through PB.

Comment: Ok. When I append my class with @invokablemethod and try to add it in Process builder then i am prompted as 'Set values for Apex method variables by entering literal values or referencing field values from a related record. The values must match the variable's data type.' What does this mean ?